# Convert json to symfony php

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm converting json to larvel php  and I'm wondering how you convert this:

---

**JSON:**

```
"assetList":[
  {
    "name":"https://mobilize-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1_20180730154641244030.png"
  },
  {
    "name":"https://mobilize-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1_20180730154641244030.png"
  },
  {
    "name":"https://mobilize-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1_20180730154641244030.png"
  }
]
```

**larvel php:**

```
'thumbnail' => 'assetList'['name'],
```

Your answer will look something like this:

```
 'thumbnail' => 'Your code here',
```

It is supposed to output an image there is 3 different images I just used one as an example. Right now, it is not outputting anything so it is not working maybe because it is an array and I'm not sure how you write an array like this to work. I think the array is stopping it from working. Any help would be much appreciated.

edit: I just found out that this is larvel php

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean you want to use the json in the template or your twig template is supposed to generate the same output? Can you maybe explain some more?

Comment: it is an array and I don't know how to write an array in twig php

Comment: I have now tried this: assetList'[array ('name')],

Comment: still does not work

Comment: Can you pls tell me which Framework are you using with Twig

Comment: look at my example again it should output 'thumbnail => 'array ('assetList' => 'name') something like that it symphony php

Comment: Please see my Answer below, Hope it helps

Comment: I thought it was twig but now I see it was like symphony php

Comment: I'm trying this: array['assetList' => ['name'][0]]

Comment: Seeing the array is one part of this problem. Show us the php you have to A) create or fetch this array B) what sends this to Twig and C) how is twig parsing this data. We cannot do much with data and no processing.

Comment: does anyone know what the answer is. It is with symfony

Answer (score 2):

Please see my answer below

1. First Your Json should be as below

```js
{"assetList":[
  {
    "name":"https://mobilize-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1_20180730154641244030.png"
  },
  {
    "name":"https://mobilize-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1_20180730154641244030.png"
  },
  {
    "name":"https://mobilize-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1_20180730154641244030.png"
  }
] }
```

2. First Do a Json_decode in php for your data.

   ```
   $json_data = [YOUR_JSON_DATA]
   $data_arr['data'] = json_decode($json_data,true);
   ```
3. Pass the array to twig 
   // for Symfony php framework

   ```
   $this->render("app:index.html.twig", $data_arr);
   ```
4. In your twig you need to update the code as below to show the Image urls

   ```
   {% for img_data in data.assetList %}
       {{ img_data.name }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Let me know if you face any more issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a similar structure to the JSON inside Twig, you can do this as follows:

```
{% set thumbnail = { "assetList": [{"name": "http://..."}, {"name": "http://..."}] } %}
```

If you want to pass a similar structure into the view, e.g. do something like `$this->render('my_template', ['thumbnail' => ...]` then your php code to generate an array like the one in JSON could look like this:

```
[
    'assetList' => [
        [
            'name' => 'http://...',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'http://...',
        ],
    ]
]
```

edit: Also accessing it in Twig will not be `assetList["name"]` it will be:

```
{{ thumbnail["assetList"][0]["name"] }}
```

Where `0` is the offset of the list entry,i.e. 0-2, if you have 3 images.

Answer (score 0):

If you passed that `json` as an `array` towards `twig`, u would need to use a loop to read out the array `assetList`

```
{% for asset in assetList %}
    {{ asset.name }}
{% endfor %}
```